# Three.js Applying a random image to each of the faces of each cube in a group of cubes

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am new to three.js and WebGL so please bear with me :)

Using http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/examples/webgl_geometry_hierarchy.html as a starting point I was able to map 6 images to each of the faces of a cube. This cube then gets replicated creating the effect as show here:

http://assemblylondon.com/clients/dmsr/ss16/1/

What I would like to do is to have an array of x amount of images (let's say 12) and have each of these 12 images applied randomly to each of the faces of each of the cubes. Having done extensive research on the topic, I am not sure if this is even possible, but would appreciate further clarification or confirmation.

Here's my code atm:

```
var camera, scene, renderer;

        var geometry, group;

        var mouseX = 0, mouseY = 0;

        var windowHalfX = window.innerWidth / 2;
        var windowHalfY = window.innerHeight / 2;

        document.addEventListener( 'mousemove', onDocumentMouseMove, false );

        init();
        animate();

        function init() {

            container = document.createElement( 'div' );
            document.body.appendChild( container );

            camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 40, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 10000 );
            camera.position.z = 500;

            scene = new THREE.Scene();

            var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 100, 100, 100 );
            var material = new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial( [
                new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( '1.jpg' ) } ),
                new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( '2.jpg' ) } ),
                new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( '3.jpg' ) } ),
                new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( '4.jpg' ) } ),
                new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( '5.jpg' ) } ),
                new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( '6.jpg' ) } )
                ] );

            group = new THREE.Group();

            for ( var i = 0; i < 60; i ++ ) {

                var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
                mesh.position.x = Math.random() * 1000 - 500;
                mesh.position.y = Math.random() * 1000 - 500;
                mesh.position.z = Math.random() * 1000 - 500;

                mesh.rotation.x = Math.random() * 2 * Math.PI;
                mesh.rotation.y = Math.random() * 2 * Math.PI;

                mesh.matrixAutoUpdate = false;
                mesh.updateMatrix();

                group.add( mesh );

            }

            scene.add( group );

            renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { alpha: true } );
            renderer.setClearColor( 0x000000, 0 );
            renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
            renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
            renderer.sortObjects = false;

            container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );



    //

    window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );

}

function onWindowResize() {

    windowHalfX = window.innerWidth / 2;
    windowHalfY = window.innerHeight / 2;

    camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

}

function onDocumentMouseMove(event) {

    mouseX = ( event.clientX - windowHalfX ) * 1;
    mouseY = ( event.clientY - windowHalfY ) * 1;

}

    //

    function animate() {

        requestAnimationFrame( animate );

        render();


    }

    function render() {

        var time = Date.now() * 0.001;

        var rx = Math.sin( time * 0.7 ) * 0.5,
        ry = Math.sin( time * 0.3 ) * 0.5,
        rz = Math.sin( time * 0.2 ) * 0.5;

        camera.position.x += ( mouseX - camera.position.x ) * .05;
        camera.position.y += ( - mouseY - camera.position.y ) * .05;

        camera.lookAt( scene.position );

        group.rotation.x = rx;
        group.rotation.y = ry;
        group.rotation.z = rz;

        renderer.render( scene, camera );

    }
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

So you just want to randomize the images?

```
// create Array of basic image materials.  
var images = [
  new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( '1.jpg' ) } ),
  new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( '2.jpg' ) } ),
  new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( '3.jpg' ) } ),
  new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( '4.jpg' ) } ),
  new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( '5.jpg' ) } ),
  new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( '6.jpg' ) } ),
  new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( '7.jpg' ) } ),
  new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( '8.jpg' ) } )
];
group = new THREE.Group();
for ( var i = 0; i < 60; i ++ ) {
  // clone the array so we can splice some out, this way an image wont be applied twice to the same cube.
  var clone = images.splice(0);
  var newArray = [];
  for(var j = 0, j < 6, j++){
    newArray[j] = clone.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * clone.length-1), 1);
  }
  // create material.
  var material = new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial(newArray);
  var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
  mesh.position.x = Math.random() * 1000 - 500;
  mesh.position.y = Math.random() * 1000 - 500;
  mesh.position.z = Math.random() * 1000 - 500;
  mesh.rotation.x = Math.random() * 2 * Math.PI;
  mesh.rotation.y = Math.random() * 2 * Math.PI;
  mesh.matrixAutoUpdate = false;
  mesh.updateMatrix(); 
  group.add( mesh );
}
scene.add( group );
```

This is untested, but you get the idea.

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work, I got this error **TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'Ua.uniforms')'** — Also I replaced the commas for semicolons in `for(var j = 0, j < 6, j++)`